# Getting 400 as status code in cosmo DB batch Operation

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to store multiple types of Records in Cosmo DB using batch operation. But I am getting 400 status in CosmoBatchResponse object and errorMessage is null. Internally , one item is giving 400 , all the other operations have a 424 status code (failed dependency). From this [document] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/http-status-codes-for-cosmosdb I can see there could be many reason of 400 , but if errorMessage is null then how to find what went wrong . Also , same msg is getting stored via create call ,facing issue while batch save only.

```
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("customerNo");
CosmosBatch batch = CosmosBatch.createCosmosBatch(partitionKey);
batch.createItemOperation(customer);
```

I have tried to store via create method only looping on CosmosItemOperation and it is getting stored.

```
  CosmosBatchResponse response=paymentRepository.createBatch(cosmosBatch);
for(CosmosItemOperation itemOp:cosmosBatch.getOperations()) {
    System.out.println(paymentRepository.create(itemOp.getItem(),""));// Here it is getting stored. 
}


public CosmosBatchResponse createBatch(CosmosBatch cosmosBatch) {
CosmosBatchResponse response = null;
try {
  response = container.executeCosmosBatch(cosmosBatch);
  System.out.println(response.isSuccessStatusCode());  -- returns false
  System.out.println(response.getErrorMessage());      -- returns null
  return response;
} catch (final Exception e) {                          
  int statusCode = CosmosUtils.getCosmosStatusCode(e);
  if (CONFLICT_RESOURCE == statusCode) {
    log.error(
        "CosmosCreateDocumentException: Resource already exists for Document : {}",
        response.getErrorMessage());
  }
  shouldRetryOnException(e);
  log.error(
      "CosmosCreateDocumentException for Document {} - {}, {}", cosmosBatch, e.getMessage(), e);
  throw new GenericRepositoryException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit to add more details, such as an example payload you're trying to add within a transactional batch, how you set up the container (e.g. partition key), typical size of the batch, etc. Are all documents within the same partition key value? Is your batch size within the limit? Etc.

Comment: The same messages when I am trying to store via only create call are getting saved , getting issue while saving them in batch only .

Comment: Ok, but you haven't answered what I was asking (e.g. are they all with the same partition key value?). And please *edit your question* - these details really need to be in your question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes partition key is same .

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have checked in CosmosBatchResponse all objects have same PK.

Comment: What is the SubStatus of the one that has 400?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta It is 0

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into exact same issue where the cosmos createItemOperation worked with stored procedure but failed with cosmos batch when writing exact same set of items. Cosmos batch returned 400 with subStatus code 0, and null error message.

In my case I found the cosmos batch only works if I set a valid "ttl" value at the item level, whereas the stored procedure does not require a "ttl" set at the item level no matter how the "ttl" is configured at container level.

I didn't find any documentation saying that the "ttl" is required for the cosmos batch operation and I haven't found the actual solution aside the workaround that I mentioned above yet, looking for more updates in this post.